# regular expr question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i'v got such string `<>1 <>2 <>3` 
i want remove all '<>' and symbols after '<>' i want replace with such expression like `www.test.com/1.jpg, www.test.com/2.jpg, www.test.com/3.jpg`

is it possible to do with regex? i only know to find '/<>.?/'

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your description what you really want. Can you please **edit your posting** and add a **real world** example, not a simplification which you expect to be representative?

Comment: But still then you can not use a generic regular expression solution, because you have a individual mapping from each pattern to a replacement. As far as I can understand your request...

Comment: why would you store strings in this format any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '<>1 <>2 <>3';

$temp = explode(' ',preg_replace('/<>(\d)/','www.test.com/\1.jpg',$string));
$newString = implode(', ',$temp);

echo $newString;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace('<>', 'www.test.com/', $input);

// pseudo code
pre_replace_all('~<>([0-9]+)~', 'www.test.com/$1.jpg', $input);
```

Comment: sorry i ask not clearly, i need template like www.test.com/bla/1/test so put symbol in any position

Answer (score 2):

```
   preg_replace('/<>(\d+)/g', 'www.test.com/bla/$1.jpg', $input);
```

(assuming your replaced elements are just numbers. If they are more general, you'll need to replace '\d+' by something else).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, I don’t think you need regex at all.

```
$str = '<>1 <>2 <>3';
print_r(str_replace('<>', 'www.test.com/', $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex's allow you to manipulate a string in any fashion you desire, to modify the string in the fashion you desire you would use the following regex:

<>(\d)

and you would use regex back referencing to keep the values you have captured in your grouping brackets, in this case a single digit. The back reference is typically signified by the $ symbol and then the number of the group you are referencing. As follows:

www.test.com/$1

this would be used in a regex replace scenario which would be implemented in different ways depending on the language you are implementing your regex replace method in.